# Is there a lounge in the International side of Cairns airport?

Tags: airports, international-travel, lounges, cairns, cns

In a few weeks time, I'm flying internationally from Cairns airport. I'm wondering if there's a lounge there that I'll have access to, as that affects how early/late I'll want to get to the airport for.

I've had a look on the [Cairns Airport passenger facilities page](http://www.cairnsairport.com.au/passenger-facilities/), and it details about the [Qantas domestic club lounge](http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/lounge-locations/cairns/domestic/the-qantas-club/global/en), but nothing about any lounges in the international side.

Is there a lounge in the international side of the airport? And if so, what are the rules on who can enter it (frequent travellers, business class passengers etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lounge, but the airport website doesn't seem to mention it...

It's a third party lounge, the Reef Lounge.

[Cathay Pacific offer their status + business class customers access](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_AU/travel-information/airport/lounges/lounge-details.CNS.html) to it, as apparently do JetStar for their Economy Starter Max and Business Max passengers.

You can also get access to the lounge with a [Priority Pass card](http://www.prioritypass.com/). The Priority Pass website has quite a lot of details on it, but I can't work out how to link to the page, so you'll need to [start on the homepage](http://www.prioritypass.com/), pick Australia + Cairns + Reef Lounge to see all about it!